# Regular expression reaname folders Métamorphose

Tags: python, regex

[image]

i try to rename batch folders with [Métamorphose](http://file-folder-ren.sourceforge.net/)
i want to use regular expression to rename folders like this:

```
Adobe.Flash.Player.14.00.125.ie
```

to:

```
Adobe Flash Player 14.00.125 ie
```

replace "." (dot) with " " (space).

and "." (dot) between numbers skiped. ie:14.00.125 in above.

[Métamorphose](http://file-folder-ren.sourceforge.net/) use python regular expression.

how i can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following if lookaround assertions are supported ( *the [documentation](http://fossies.org/linux/privat/metamorphose-1.1.2.tar.gz/metamorphose-1.1.2/docs/en_US/REhelp.html) states they are*.. )

```
Search: (?<!\d)\.|\.(?=\D)
Replace with: 
              ^ space character
```

[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/wK1sO7/1)

Answer (score 0):

This will match any `.` between letters only on the left and letters and numbers on the right and replace it with a space.

```
re.sub("([0-9])\.([a-zA-Z])",r"\1 \2",(re.sub("([a-zA-Z]|[0-9])\.([a-zA-Z0-9])",r"\1 \2",str)))
```

**Edited to add the case for `[0-9].[a-zA-Z]`. I used two `re.sub` calls instead of using `|` to match multiple patterns because I'm running into a weird error when trying to reference the matched groups in the substitution string.