# Python Regex Unmatched Groups error with multiple patterns

Tags: python, regex

So I was trying to answer a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24918663/regular-expression-reaname-folders-m%C3%A9tamorphose) on SO when I ran into this issue. Basically a user had the following string:

```
Adobe.Flash.Player.14.00.125.ie
```

and wanted to replace it with

```
Adobe Flash Player 14.00.125 ie
```

so I used the following `re.sub` call to solve this issue:

```
re.sub("([a-zA-Z])\.([a-zA-Z0-9])",r"\1 \2",str)
```

I then realized that doesn't remove the dot between `125` and `ie` so I figured I'd try to match another pattern namely:

```
re.sub("([a-zA-Z])\.([a-zA-Z0-9])|([0-9])\.([a-zA-Z])",r"\1\3 \2\4",str)
```

When I try to run this, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/re.py", line 151, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, 0).sub(repl, string, count)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/re.py", line 278, in filter
    return sre_parse.expand_template(template, match)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/sre_parse.py", line 793, in expand_template
    raise error, "unmatched group"
sre_constants.error: unmatched group
```

Now, I understand that it's complaining because I'm trying to replace the match with an unmatched group but is there a way around this without having to call `re.sub` twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any capturing groups,

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "Adobe.Flash.Player.14.00.125.ie"
>>> m = re.sub(r'\.(?=[A-Za-z])|(?<!\d)\.', r' ', s)
>>> m
'Adobe Flash Player 14.00.125 ie'
```

Comment: Yeah, another answer on that question used this method. I was interested in seeing how you can reference captured groups if they don't match. 

+1 for an alternative.

Comment: if we use the logical OR  operator in regex while back-referencing, then it's impossible to refer the grouped characters  through back reference.

Comment: Aha. Thanks @Avinash Raj

Comment: The main thing in regex is, we need to solve the problem without any capturing groups(ie; through matching only). If it's not possible through matching then only we go for grouping.